# chmod - deny file delete for the owner of the directory

Tags: ftp, chmod

I have a folder with drwxrwxr-x permissions, where the owner is uploading his own files.
I want to upload on that directory a readme file. The owner of the folder shouldn't have the right to delete that file. How I can do that? What rights should I set for the directory & for the file.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of doing this with ACLs, but the easiest way, if your OS supports it, is to make `readme` an immutable file. A file with the immutable flag can't be modified, deleted, or renamed, even by the owner or the owner of the containing directory. On Linux, this would be done with `sudo chattr +i /path/to/directory/readme`.  On Linux, not even the owner of a file can remove the immutable flag (well, unless the owner can run a process with the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability).

Answer (score 0):

The file should have drwxr--r--, this way only you, the owner of the file, have the ability to delete it.

```
chmod 744 <file>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.
The owner of the directory is usernameftp:apache.
And for the file the owner is apache:apache and chmod 744, but "usernameftp" is still able to delete the file.